# Change maxValue of Medusa Gauge while programm is active

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am new in this forum and also to programming. Furthermore, my English is not the best, but I hope you can understand what I mean and help me out.

I want to program a GUI and using JavaFX and the Gauges from the medusa- library. What I need to do is changing the maxValue and the minValue of the Gauge while the program is running. I can change the values, but the scale of the Gauge does not rearrange the ticks properly. For example, when I create a Gauge from 0 to 10 and then set the maxValue to 100, the scale shows all numbers as a major tick and the scale becomes unreadable. Because I could not find how to fix this, I have tried to delete the original Gauge and create simply a new one.

Here is what I have tried(I deleted the rest of the class, because it has over 800 lines):

```
package application;

import eu.hansolo.medusa.Gauge;
import eu.hansolo.medusa.Gauge.SkinType;
import eu.hansolo.medusa.GaugeBuilder;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Controller {

@FXML
StackPane stackPane;

private Gauge gauge;
private Button button;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    gauge = GaugeBuilder.create().skinType(SkinType.QUARTER).barBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHTGREY)
            .needleColor(Color.RED).decimals(0).valueVisible(true).valueColor(Color.BLACK).title("Stromstärke")
            .unit("[mA]").subTitle("Phase 1").minValue(0).maxValue(10).build();

    stackPane.getChildren().add(gauge);
}

public void setMaxValueGauge(StackPane pStackPane, Gauge pGauge, int intMinValue, int pMaxValue) {
    pStackPane.getChildren().remove(pGauge);
    Gauge newGauge = GaugeBuilder.create().skinType(pGauge.getSkinType()).barBackgroundColor(pGauge.getBarColor())
            .needleColor(pGauge.getNeedleColor()).decimals(0).valueVisible(true).valueColor(Color.BLACK)
            .title(pGauge.getTitle()).unit(pGauge.getUnit()).subTitle(pGauge.getSubTitle()).minValue(intMinValue)
            .maxValue(pMaxValue).build();
    pGauge = null;
    pGauge = newGauge;
    pStackPane.getChildren().add(pGauge);
}

@FXML
public void testButton() {
    setMaxValueGauge(stackPane, gauge, 0, 30);
}

}

The method testButton() is only for testing. When I call testButton() the first time, it works well, but when I use it twice or more, it seems that the old Gauge is not replaced. Instead the new one stacks on top of the old one.
```

Can you please help me. I need either to fix the ticks of the scale, when I set a new maxValue, or to properly replace the old Gauge in the Stackpane.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be doing too much to set the max-value.

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that changes the maxValue.

```
import eu.hansolo.medusa.Gauge;
import eu.hansolo.medusa.Gauge.SkinType;
import eu.hansolo.medusa.GaugeBuilder;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class MedusaGaugeTest extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Gauge gauge = GaugeBuilder.create().skinType(SkinType.QUARTER).barBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHTGREY)
                .needleColor(Color.RED).decimals(0).valueVisible(true).valueColor(Color.BLACK).title("Stromstärke")
                .unit("[mA]").subTitle("Phase 1").minValue(0).maxValue(10).build();;

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
            if (gauge.getValue() <= gauge.getMaxValue()) {
                gauge.setValue(gauge.getValue() + 1);
            }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Start");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            timeline.play();
        });

        Button btn2 = new Button();
        btn2.setText("Increase MaxValue");
        btn2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            gauge.setMaxValue(15);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(gauge, new VBox(btn, btn2));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```